# Am I fetching data from database the right way?PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm learning php and mysql, and I had trouble with fetching data from database with php and displaying it on the page instead of hard coding it into html. I managed to do it, but can't help feeling like it's a workaround and not actually how it's supposed to be done. I'm trying to display a title for an article instead of typing the title in html.

```
<a href="#">
   <h3>
     <?php
      $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT srtdsc FROM news WHERE id=2")); 
      print $row[0];  
     ?>
   </h3>
</a>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines. In its current form it does *not* meet their requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is basic, there are lots of ways to improve on this. But you have to start somewhere and learn those basics first. getting something to work is a great start.

Some other basics you could focus on to improve this specific piece of code (perhaps you already know some of these too):
 - learn how to get the record Id from the URL
 - Separate your code, do not mix displaying code (in your case your PHP/html template) with database logic. Split that stuff into separate classes and files
- if you retrieve data from your database using a regular array like you have now, changes to your database query may force you to change your template, if you retrieve the data via an associative array (there are mysqli commands for that) you can get the value like this: $row['srtdsc']
- do not use the mysqli library, but rather the modern PDO library for your database connections. 
- do not build your queries by concatenating strings, but use prepared statements to help prevent SQL injection security issues
- try to implement your application using a simple design pattern such as MVC to help separate your code to make the solution more maintainable and flexible.